# was windows os written from scratch?

Tags: windows, operating-system

What is it's background and "inspiration" if any? Does it by any chance have fragments of Unix DNA deep within it but not disclosed for whatever reasons?

Comment: [History of Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Windows)

Answer (score 2):

No it wasn't.

MS-DOS was a renamed and ported to IBM PC clone of CP/M OS bought from Seattle Computer Products by Microsoft (this goes to all Windows from beginning and to Windows 98/Me)

If talking about Windows based on NT, Microsoft hired a team of engineers (headed by Dave Cutler, one of DEC's VMS operating system developer) from DEC company. He was told to develop a 32-bit OS with supporting the OS/2 API. So at the end, new OS (NT OS/2) was really similar to VMS, and later, based on this new NT OS/2, Windwows NT 3.1 was released  in 1993.

P.S. This information was taken from a book I've read -- [Modern Operating Systems, 3-th edition. Author: Andrew S. Tanenbaum.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Operating_Systems)